# Generating json file from dict python with changing values from function

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have functions witch generate data witch I add  t dict the think is there I want my json file to look like this 1.to have multiple data not only one key value pair like in my code:

```
    {"data":[  
    {"key":"Shyam", "value":10.4},  
    {"key":"Bob", "value":12.5},  
    {"key":"Jai", "value":24.2}  
]}
```

This is how is look like the moment only one key value pair is added:

```
{
"key": "Amadm",
"value": 14.5
}
```

This is my code to assign to dict before json dumps.
:

```
def gen_dict(key, value, ts):
    data = {
    "name": key,
    "value": value,
    "ts": ts
    }
    return data

json_object = json.dumps(gen_dict(gen_key(), gen_value()), indent = 4)
```

So my question is how to assign more than one key value pair in the dict and later to transform to json obj like in the example I show in the example.

Comment: is this question basically about how to add new keys to an existing dict? or how to populate a new dict with multiple keys? that should well be covered in the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: I need my json to be with more then one object I don't know how to do this since my function produce one dict at a time.

Comment: then you should modify your function to either produce a dict with all the values you need, or to update an existing dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a single dictionary, what you want is a list of dictionaries:

Assuming that you each call to `gen_key()` and  `gen_value()` generates a single instance of the data, you can use:

```
# Some random key
def gen_key():
  return ''.join((random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(5))) 

# Some random value
def gen_value():
  return random.choice(range(1000))

s = json.dumps({"data": [ {
    "name": gen_key(), "value": gen_value()} for i in range(3)] }, indent = 4)
```

output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "rrqct",
            "value": 162
        },
        {
            "name": "vbuyq",
            "value": 422
        },
        {
            "name": "kfyqt",
            "value": 7
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok that is what I need Thank you